# How to find my websites localhost?

Tags: web, localhost, siteorigin

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign-In to my website and it's asking me to give the localhost or origin of my site which I don't know where or how to find this.

If anyone know how to do this please let me know!

Comment: What kind of site do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Wordpress, your localhost can be found in your wp-config.php file.

This can be accessed by your file manager or ftp. It would be in the /public_html/ directory.